# Create a list of all indexes - given count/size

Tags: java

Is there a more elegant way of creating a list of all the indexes?

```
    private List<Integer> getIndexList(final int count) {
            final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(count);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                list.add(i);
            }
            return list;
    }
```

List Output:

> <[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]>

Comment: This should work in most cases: `Range.closed(a, b).asSet(DiscreteDomains.integers());` you can replace a,b with the start and length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with Streams :

```
List<Integer> indexList = IntStream.range(0,list.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: was just gonna post exactly the same line

Comment: `list.size()` -> `count`.

Comment: @saka1029 That's correct in this example, but I prefer to rely on `list.size()`.